# How can I count only guests comments?

Tags: comments, count

I need to ignore counting author replies within comments number function, for example If I have 9 replies (comments) which 4 of them appertain to post author, I would display 5 comments as comments number in my post.

Do you know any method to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these inside `the loop`, or in `comments.php`

```
//The author of current post
$author_ID = get_the_author_meta("ID");
//The current post ID
$p_ID = get_the_ID();
//Number of guest comments
echo count(get_comments(array(
                'post_id' => $p_ID,
                'author__not_in' => array($author_ID)
            )));
```

More: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments